# Can a single RAM module of a set of two dual-channel SODIMMs work without a counterpart?

Tags: laptop, memory, dual-channel

My problem is that a Dell XPS 15 9570 laptop refuses to boot (memory detection error) when Kingston KF426S15IB1K2/32 modules are inserted.

In relation to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1764914/incompatibility-of-kingston-fury-32-gib-with-dell-xps-15-9570) it's been suggested to me elsewhere that it looks like one of the memory modules is faulty and that an easy way to check it is to insert just one of them at a time and try to boot. (The probability that both are faulty is very low, about a square of that of just one.)

Is that sound advice? I have a doubt, given that Kingston [write](https://www.kingston.com/support/technical/products/desktop-notebook-memory):

> Parts sold in kits (denoted by "K2" or "K3"in the part number, e.g. – KVR400X64C3AK2/2G) are specifically packaged for use in Dual or Triple Channel motherboards. Although Dual and Triple Channel technology resides on the motherboard itself (inside the chipset), the memory modules need to be installed in pairs or sets of three for Dual or Triple Channel mode to function properly.

Comment: This question is about a different thing: feasibility of using (in my case just for diagnostics) just one module of a pair. That's why I asked it separately instead of e.g. adding a comment there.

Comment: The Kingston memo is merely a reminder for proper Dual or Triple Channel operation. You can always revert to basic Single-Channel operation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes RAM sticks can always be used separately. They are often sold in kits of two because most often a motherboard will have two RAM channels which is just a method used to increase performance.

Even though they are sold as a pair, they are two completely independent modules.

Note: Channels are not slots and a motherboard may for example have 4 slots but only two channels in which case it supports two sticks per channel.